# Unable to append value in loop using Php

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I am working with php and phpexcel,I have following array($data) i want to search and append array value in php,For example i want to change "link" value(want to add "txt" with previous value) of user whose email id is "cde@gmail.com",But its not working properly, i mean after refresh page , its removing previous "appended" value and append current value,but i want keep previous value also,Ho can i do this ? Here is my current array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [email] => abc@gmail.com
            [link] => abc,xyz,def
         )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [email] => cde@gmail.com
            [link] => cde,abb
        )
...
```

Expected result (adding "bbb" instead of removing "abb")

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [email] => abc@gmail.com
            [link] => abc,xyz,def
         )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [email] => cde@gmail.com
            [link] => cde,abb,bbb
        )
...
```

I tried with following code but "removing" previous value ("abb"),i want to append new value with previous

```
$searchEmail = 'cde@gmail.com';
$appendString = 'bbb';
foreach ($set_excel_query_all as $key => &$item) {
   if ($item['email'] == $searchEmail) {
      $item['link'] .= ',' . $appendString;
      break;
   }
}
unset($item);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same error yesterday and same mistake as you have done here.
Try this code

```
$searchEmail = 'cde@gmail.com';
$appendString = 'bbb';
foreach ($set_excel_query_all as $key => $item) {
if ($item['email'] == $searchEmail) {
  $set_excel_query_all[$key]['link'] .= ',' . $appendString;
  break;
}
}
unset($item);
```